# What is the connection between entretien and interview/maintenance

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie

Can anyone explain me why the word "entretien" is used for "interview" and "maintenance". Due to Etymology I can see why it's used for 'interview', but can't wrap my head around why its used for 'maintenance'. Any idea is highly appreciated!

Comment: Consider looking into the different meanings of the verb [_entretenir_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/entretenir#fr). It's not unusual for words to have more than one meaning. Note interview is from French _entrevue_ (see etymonline) but interview is also used in Fr... What do you mean by "due to etymology" exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that entretenir is a verb with a lot of signification due to its versatility. You can entretenir une conversation just like you can entretenir une salle de bain. A translation of the verb would be like taking care of. An interview is an entretien because you talk to someone: you take care of the conversation. You can also use it like maintenance because you can take care of an object for example.

Hope I helped you!

Comment: Wow, that’s a really great explanation! Thanks